# Make a UIViewPropertyAnimator never complete

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

### Problem Description

I have a `UIViewPropertyAnimator` managing a blur, among other things, and I'd like to use it just for its `fractionComplete` property. The problem is that if I set `fractionComplete` to `1.0`, it completes and removes all animations, which I'd like to keep.

Basically, I don't want the animator to complete because that clears its animation blocks.

### Workarounds considered

- Re-add animations upon completion
- Clamp `fractionComplete` to something like `0.001...0.999`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With iOS11 is now possible to set

```swift
var pausesOnCompletion: Bool { get set }
```

on the `UIViewPropertyAnimator`

> When the value of this property is true, the animator remains in the 
>   active state when the animation finishes, and it does not execute its
>   completion handler. Keeping the animator in the active state allows
>   you to reverse the animation even after it has finished. When the
>   value of this property is false, the animator automatically
>   transitions to the  inactive state when the animation finishes,
>   thereby concluding the animation. The default value of this property
>   is false.

source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewpropertyanimator/2909004-pausesoncompletion