# UIViewPropertyAnimator reverse animation

Tags: ios, uikit

I have a simple pulse animation which runs perfectly

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
    myAnimatableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)
}) { _ in
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
        myAnimatableView.transform = .identity
    })
}
```

I want to make the same animation, but now with `UIViewPropertyAnimator`. Is it possible to replicate this pulse effect elegantly with the new API?

I'm doing it this way

```
let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 1, curve: .linear) {
    animatableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)
}
animator.addCompletion { _ in
    animator.isReversed = true
    animator.startAnimation()
}
animator.startAnimation()
```

but my `animatableView` is just stuck scaled to 1.2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that the property animator removes animations after completion (which would explain that starting it again would have no effect) - see [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43564406/make-a-uiviewpropertyanimator-never-complete). Based on that, You might try hacking it through `pausesOnCompletion`, but I would expect that that would not be as easy as you might think. Simply because the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewpropertyanimator/2909004-pausesoncompletion) says:

> When the value of this property is true, the animator remains in the active state when the animation finishes, and **it does not execute its completion handler.**

That means that completion handler won't get called, if the `pauseOnCompletion` is set to true. According to the same documentation, you can determine when the animator ended (and thus when you should restart the animation) by observing `isRunning` property of the animator. However, when I tried to implement that, I found out that KVO on `isRunning` does not get called during the lifecycle of the animator. Thus my recommendation in the end is to simply use two animators, because it seems much easier to implement:

```
let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 1, curve: .linear) {
    animatableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)
}
animator.addCompletion { _ in
    let secondAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 1, curve: .linear) {
        animatableView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    }
    secondAnimator.startAnimation()
}
animator.startAnimation()
```

Comment: thanks! I thought maybe with `UIViewPropertyAnimator` my code could look prettier, but apparently it's more useful in more complicated cases.

Comment: I find it most useful in case when scrubbing is involved (when you want to control the animation from your code by setting `animator.fractionComplete`)

Comment: ok, will give it another try with some interactive animations!

Comment: The reason `isRunning` doesn't get called is because it is implemented in ojbc and the value is actually just `running`. This took me forever to figure out!

Answer (score 2):

I think your code is more appropiated translated like this

**Try with this code**

```
    let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 1, curve: .linear) {
        self.animatableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)
    }
    animator.addAnimations({
        self.animatableView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    }, delayFactor: 0.5)
    animator.startAnimation()
```

Or you can try with `UILayer` animations

**Try using UILayer animations**

```
let layerAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
layerAnimation.fromValue = 1
layerAnimation.toValue = 1.2
layerAnimation.isAdditive = false
layerAnimation.duration = CFTimeInterval(1)
layerAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
layerAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = true
layerAnimation.repeatCount = .infinity
layerAnimation.autoreverses = true

self.animatableView.layer.add(layerAnimation, forKey: "growingAnimation")
```

Comment: I checked your code with UIViewPropertyAnimator in playground and it doesn't replicate scaling correctly. UIView with 200x200 frame scaled to 1.2 should expand to 240x240, right? That how it works with UIView.animate and with your UILayer example, but not in case UIViewPropertyAnimator.